# Using Jackson XML Mapper, unexpected close tag

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm reading in a malformed XML (out of my control), the file type is of OFX. I was hoping to use Jackson XML to deserialize.
Here is a sample of the file

```
<OFX>
<SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
    <SONRS>
        <STATUS>
            <CODE>0
            <SEVERITY>INFO
            <MESSAGE>OK
        </STATUS>
        <DTSERVER>20220904084713[-5]
        <LANGUAGE>ENG
        <INTU.BID>00315
    </SONRS>
</SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
</OFX>
```

I'm using the XMLMapper like this:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.builder()
            .enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
            .configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, false)
            .build();
```

I was hoping there was a way to still parse this poorly formatted XML and ignore the missing closing tags, or do I need to create a way to read the Status Object differently?

Comment: I'm not sure how will the parser's logic will understand where it has to stop reading the node data, i.e. this is not possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14464425/2834978

Comment: Maybe look to use a library that knows how to parse OFX instead of using general XML tools for data that is not XML https://github.com/ftomassetti/ofx-java

Comment: Why would you expect XML tools to be able to handle non-XML input?